# an alternative for object_getInstanceVariable

Tags: objective-c

I think to not really understand what is the best way to upgrade the object_getInstanceVariable used in an old project.

In other word, what is the best thing to use instead of the following instruction?

```
object_getInstanceVariable(self, [[@"t" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", x] UTF8String], (UITextField **)&textField);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `valueForKey:`, e.g.:

```
textField = [self valueForKey:[@"t" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", x]];
```

Unlike your code this will find both instance variables and properties.

This will also throw an exception if the variable or property does not exist. This can be addressed by overriding `valueForUndefinedKey:` on the target class (`self` in your case).